apa7 and cleveref
I'm formatting a document with the apa7 style and would like to use the cleveref package. However, it doesn't seem to work. Here's a minimal not-working example:
\documentclass{apa7}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\title{foo}
\shorttitle{f}
\author{bar}
\affiliation{baz}
\abstract{quz}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

We refer to \cref{sec:test-section}.

\section{Test section}
\label{sec:test-section}

\end{document}

After running this twice, I get the LaTeX warnings

LaTeX Warning: cref reference format for label type `' undefined on input line
12.

and

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

and the document looks like this:

Do I just have to give up on cleveref if I'm using apa7?

@gusbrs ah right, fair enough. That seems like a bad decision to me, on the part of whoever specified the style, but I'm not in a position to complain.

From the apa7 manual:

Please note that sections cannot be \ref'd since APA style does not use numbered sections. So \label commands are unnecessary unless you wish to use \refname [sic, \nameref probably?].

So this is not specific to cleveref, not even a standard \ref would work there.
